# Is there a way to get the BLE device battery life status using Google FIT

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I know how to read the characteristic using android BluetoothGatt. but im currently integrating Google FIT, I manage to read othe characteristics from my ble device (such as heart rate) and i want to use it to pull the battery life status as well. is it possible?